# which php-fpm sock location should i use?

Tags: php-fpm, centos7, socks

Im new to server administration so forgive me if the answer is obvious.
I noticed that in different tutorials in the web people use different directory/location for the pool sock in php-fpm(On CentOS 7).
I've seen those:
1.

1. `unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;`
2. `unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;`

And both directories contain the same files.
So wich one is the right one? (i asume there is no better, but why two identical folders?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are effectively the same place as `/var/run` is a [symlink](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-symbolic-soft-and-hard-links.html) to `/run`

```
ls -l /var/run
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Dec 15 11:20 /var/run -> /run
```

You can therefore use either interchangeably.